# LWC OSS Import External Google API's

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

I am trying to utilize Google API's in a LWC component.  I am able to do a fetch in my component to a hosted API endpoint that utilizes the google API's and returns a list of Google Drive files via JSON:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const drive = google.drive('v3');
...
```

Within my LWC component, when I try to encapsulate all the logic rather than creating a generic API consumer component, I am getting the following error:

```
import { drive_v3 } from 'googleapis';     // or google
```

LWC Compilation Debug:

```
(!) Import of non-existent export
```

How can I properly import the NPM GoogleAPIs (and other NPM 3rd-party) into an LWC component?  I also tried adding an "npm" entry of "googleapis" to the lwc.config.json.

Answer (score 0):

The [LWC Module](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/tree/master/packages/%40lwc/module-resolver) resolver does not allow you to bring any third-party **npm** module in your modules. You can only import an **LWC module** that you publish to the npm.

Exporting an LWC Module to **npm** is discussed in this blog [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/09/lightning-web-components-module-resolution.html) and then only you can import it.

> The Module resolution of LWS OSS just bundles all the client-side code and gets you an ES6 module that can work with Browser! Definitely cannot resolve npm library dependencies if it uses server-side node.js

For your use case, you can simply expose a server endpoint via an express server and then use the `fetch` API call from your javascript in LWC to invoke the endpoint.

You can see a working [example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ecars/tree/main/apps/ecars-pwa) of how the `client` and `server` should be wired.

Comment: Correct, I have it already working using an api endpoint/route, returning a JSON list of Google Drive files (for example), using the fetch wire-service.  For some reason I thought the LWC controller/js would execute on the server

Comment: @paul.payne The Module resolution just bundles all the client-side code and gets you an ES6 module that can work with Browser!

Comment: @paul.payne just added a few more words to make the answer more clear!

Comment: makes sense, and thanks for the clarification on the bundle resolution.  I was originally confused since the wire adapters were returning data from my MongoDB instance, etc, so assumed the entire component was server-side, but get it's part of framework.  I guess another option would be a custom wire adapter to Google Drive?   Moving forward, need to choose how I want to expose my business logic:  all node endpoints, spring boot instance, salesforce functions / evergreen, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can import a 3rd party `npm` modules in LWC OSS. It supports both `require` and `import` methods to import a module.

```
import moment from "moment";
//or
const moment1 = require("moment");
```

Checkout [lwc-oss-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes-oss/blob/master/src/modules/recipe/libsD3/libsD3.js) on  how `d3` library is used.

You're not able to import `googleapis` because it's a NodeJS library. It's designed to work in a server environment and not a browser. When you import it into an LWC component, it'll run in a browser (but fail). Since the library has dependency on modules like `child_process`, browser cannot provide these modules as these are available in NodeJS, i.e, server environment, even if you added using `npm`.

Comment: As I mentioned to @Mohith, I have it already working using an api endpoint/route and am using the fetch wire-service.  For some reason I thought the LWC controller/js would execute on the server and I had something incorrectly configured.  thanks for clarifying